# How do I sendKeys to a ui-ace instance with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, protractor, ace-editor

I want to test some keypresses against a `ui-ace` instance.  However, Protractor can't get focus on the ace element.  Ace includes a `<textarea>` that I *can* get focus on (and thus send keys to) but `ui-ace` doesn't recognize keys inputted there (and subsequently doesn't update the model).

Selecting method (`by.model`, etc) has no impact.

My current workaround is to use `evaluate` to set the scope value manually, but this breaks the point of using Protractor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question! Seems that the workaround is double clicking first.

The following works at least on Chrome:

```
"use strict";
describe('Testing ui-ace', function() {
    var divInput = $('div.ace_content');
    var inputElm = $('textarea.ace_text-input');

    it('opens a ui-ace page', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;  // sorry but no angular page
        browser.get('http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/');
        browser.sleep(3000); // sorry but no angular page
    });

    it('starts editing', function() {
        browser.actions().doubleClick(divInput).perform();
    });

    it('enters some text', function() {
        inputElm.sendKeys('Hola');
        browser.sleep(5000); // to let you see the result
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm in the midst of a different branch right now, but I'll check out your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: that solves the problem but reading that test is a painful hack.  There are no assertions in those tests whatsoever.  Also, hard sleeping is always bad.  trying to use the browser.wait function

Comment: The waits are for the sake of simplify the answer, that's not what's the question is about. Is it really too painful to double click on an e2e test? A better answer is always welcome in Stack Overflow so feel free to issue one.

Comment: Thank you x 10000000! This saved me.

Comment: how can I get a text from the ace editor which has around 200+ lines of JSON text using protractor?